# How to move cursor at any possible point on the screen in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent

I wrote the following code to move mouse anywhere on the screen when I press the TAB key

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winuser.h>

int main() {

while(true) {

//mi0 to move mouse to top left corner of screen
INPUT mi0[1] = {0};

mi0[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
mi0[0].mi.dx = -99999; // desired X coordinate
mi0[0].mi.dy = -99999; // desired Y coordinate
mi0[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

//mi1 to move mouse and click
INPUT mi1[3] = {0};

mi1[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
mi1[0].mi.dx = 1; // desired X coordinate
mi1[0].mi.dy = 1; // desired Y coordinate
mi1[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

mi1[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
mi1[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

mi1[2].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
mi1[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

if (GetKeyState(VK_TAB) & 0x8000 ) {
Sleep(300);
SendInput(1, mi0, sizeof(INPUT));
Sleep(300);
SendInput(3, mi1, sizeof(INPUT));
}}}
```

This works fine except that dy and dx can only be integers and values like 1.9 or 1.1 are read as 1 which accounts for a significantly long length of movement so I am basically limited to a handful of points on the screen. How can I fix this and move mouse anywhere on the screen. I use Notepad++ and MinGW in case that might be relevant in any way. Any help/guidance much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to move the mouse to every coordinate, and then explain, that moving the mouse to every coordinate is too slow. Make up your mind. You cannot have both.

Comment: Check MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, and MOUSEMOVEPOINT

Comment: You are working with _screen coordinates_ and these are integers by definition. So why are you mentioning floating point values such as1.9 or 1.1?? Please elaborate your question. Also indent your code correctly for your own sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Y.S says check for MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE and MOUSEMOVEPOINT.

The dwFlags change the meaning of dx and dy. But you will never need floating value.

If MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE value is specified, dx and dy contain normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535. The event procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate (0,0) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface; coordinate (65535,65535) maps onto the lower-right corner.

If this flag is not set the mouse move of dx pixels and dy pixels from the previous position.

from :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx